# how to trigger an event when an item is selected from combobox in c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

```
        string Sql_type = "select property_type_id,type_name from lk_tb_property_type";

        OleDbCommand cmd_type = new OleDbCommand(Sql_type, con);

        OleDbDataReader DR_two = cmd_type.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable table_two = new DataTable();
        table_two.Load(DR_two);

        //begin adding line
        DataRow row_two = table_two.NewRow();
        row_two["type_name"] = "Select Poperty Name";
        row_two["property_type_id"] = 0;
        table_two.Rows.InsertAt(row_two, 0);
        //end adding a line


        combo_type.DataSource = table_two;


        combo_type.DisplayMember = "type_name";
        combo_type.ValueMember = "property_type_id";
        combo_type.Text = "Select Poperty Name";
```

with this code i am fetching values for a combobox from database.now suppose my combobx is having 2 items named A and B..I have one more combobox...now what i want is that when user chooses item A from combobox the second combobox should display  data related to item A when  user chooses item B then data related to item B should be displayed...sohow to achieve this...??

Comment: Did you try `SelectedIndexChanged` property?

Comment: i tried but it is not working...i think i did something wrong in it

Comment: @user3181292 show the code what you have tried so far

Comment: Do you get any error? If yes, what?

Comment: what error you getting, where you stuck Please tell

Comment: i am posting my code again ...please wait

Answer (score 2):

you can fetch the data and bind it to combobox2 on `SelectedIndexChanged` event of combobox1

```
private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var val = combobox1.SelectedValue;
     // fetch data from database 
     // you need to set SQL parameter value form SelectedValue

     combobox2.DataSource = ...; // set this value 
     combobox2.DisplayMember = .....; // set this value 
     combobox2.ValueMember = ....; // set this value 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please assign an event `SelectedIndexChanged` and `AutoPostBack = true` is this is a web Application in C#

Answer (score 0):

In **SelectedIndexChanged** of combo box write your code. and make **AutoPostBack = true** of your combobox

Comment: AutoPostBack = true ...what does it do vikas??

Comment: @user3181292 is this asp.net application?

Comment: when AutoPostBack = true, on every change of selected value of  combobox, SelectedIndexChanged event is triggered

Comment: he is using combox,datatable,datasource from all this I assume it is in asp.net

Comment: I think he is working with Windows Form, because he mentions ComboBox and it's no have AutoPostBack properties. In asp .net should call DropDownlist which has AutoPostBack to set.

Comment: @MotomotoPink yes I also think he is working in winform

Comment: there is no `DisplayMember` or `ValueMember` in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

You can do like these steps.
First, bind data to comboBox1 (I suppose that your first ComboBox named "comboBox1", and your form named "Form1"), **please make sure that your SQL query command is correct for comboBox1**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);

    con.Open();
    string Sql_cust_name = "select customer_name from tb_customer";

    OleDbCommand cmd_cust_name = new OleDbCommand(Sql_cust_name, con);

    OleDbDataReader DR_cust_name = cmd_cust_name.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable table_cust_name = new DataTable();
    table_cust_name.Load(DR_cust_name);

    DataRow row_cust_name = table_cust_name.NewRow();
    row_cust_name["customer_name"] = "Select Customer Name";

    table_cust_name.Rows.InsertAt(row_cust_name, 0);

    combo_cust_name.DataSource = table_cust_name;
    combo_cust_name.DisplayMember = "customer_name";
    combo_cust_name.ValueMember = "customer_name";
    combo_cust_name.Text = "Select Customer Name";

    con.Close();
}
```

Next, bind data to comboBox2 (I suppose that your second ComboBox named "comboBox2"), you have to get `comboBox1.SelectedValue` whenever it is changed, this value will be used in the filtering for data in comboBox2, so you have to handle SelectedIndexChanged event for comboBox1, please make sure that you have this code somewhere in your project: `this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);`

To bind data to comboBox2 (I suppose that your second ComboBox named "comboBox2"), you have to get comboBox1.SelectedValue whenever it is changed

```
private void combo_cust_name_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);

    con.Open();

    string customerName = "";
    if (combo_cust_name.SelectedValue.GetType() == typeof(DataRowView))
    {
        DataRowView selectedRow = (DataRowView)combo_cust_name.SelectedValue;
        customerName = selectedRow["customer_name"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        customerName = combo_cust_name.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }

    string Sql2 = "SELECT customer_number FROM tb_customer WHERE customer_name = '" + customerName + "'";
    OleDbCommand cmd_type = new OleDbCommand(Sql2, con);

    OleDbDataReader DR_two = cmd_type.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable table_two = new DataTable();
    table_two.Load(DR_two);

    DataRow row_two = table_two.NewRow();
    row_two["customer_number"] = "Select Customer Number";
    table_two.Rows.InsertAt(row_two, 0); 

    comboBox2.DataSource = table_two;
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "customer_number";
    comboBox2.ValueMember = "customer_number";
    comboBox2.Text = "Select Customer Number"; 
}
```

Please correct the SQL query command as you want, but don't forget to put a correct filter like my sample code above.

Comment: i tried your code but it is not working...what can i do now ??

Comment: i am so sry...i again tried it and it worked...your code really helped me...thnxxx...:)

Comment: Yes, what's the prob?

Comment: nw the situation is changed...now i am fetching a name from database in the first combobox and i want to fetch customer number in the second combobox ...but here Convert.ToInt32 this thing is giving problem...the datatyp of customer number is text..what should i change in this code??

Comment: could you give me your mail id so that i could ask u it is not working??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45464/discussion-between-motomoto-pink-and-user3181292)